# Your app does not appear in the ‘My Apps’ launcher after authentication

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

we've created an single-signon with office for our webbapp.

Now we created an app for the office-store, but it was rejected with "Your app does not appear in the ‘My Apps’ launcher after authentication."

What we are currently doing:

- send the user to https://login.windows.net/" + Configuration.getOfficeTenant() + "/oauth2/authorize
- Fetch a token with the code https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Configuration.getOfficeTenant() + "/oauth2/token
- and then parse the id_token to get users name and email and log him in

How can we controll the "‘My Apps’ launcher" of the user? Do we need to make an additional api call? The page "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/connect-your-app-to-o365-app-launcher" does not really point me to a solution - it seems that it should happen autmatically

Comment: Hey @wutzbaer... is this application a 'multi-tenant' application? In other words, is any user with an Office 365 account supposed to be able to sign in to the app?

Comment: Also, how did you go about registering the application?

Comment: yes it is multi-tenant, i registered it here: https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com/Application/Summary

Comment: When a user of a new organization signs in for the first time, do they see the consent screen that asks for the permissions your app needs?

Comment: don't know i have no account left, you could check it on brainyoo.de

Comment: It did not do so for me. If this is a multi tenant app, you should send the user to login.microsoftonline.com/common. You should only send users to login.microsoftonline.com/<guid> if you know which tenant the user belongs to ahead of time.

Comment: Also I believe you need to configure the "Enable Sign On and read user profile" permission for your application

Comment: "Enable Sign On and read user profile" is already checked unter "deligated permissions ... wehn i use "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id... the pages shows "an invalid request has been received"

Comment: Is that the entire error message provided at the bottom of the page in the technical details?

Comment: yes: AADSTS90093: This operation can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators.